# With SQL, replace string in only one paragraph of large text field in a performant way (using Substring, Locate and Replace, RegEx, whatever, etc)

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

I have a MySQL database where every record has a large text field with many paragraphs..

I need to replace a specific word in just the last paragraph, which always starts with **"Summary:"**

The specific word to replace exists in other paragraphs where it should NOT be replaced !

**Contents of textfield:**

> Paragraph1: sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf 
>   dcs fsdf sdf sdf sdf sdf **[my_word]** sdf sdf
>
> Paragraph2: sdf fg rg dfg dgf **[my_word]** sdf sdf sdf
>   sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf s
>
> ParagraphN:  sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdfdf gdfg
>
> **Summary:**  sdf sdf **[my_word]** sdf sdf sdf sdf 
>   sdf sdf sdf sdsdfsdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf

- The target word doesn't exist in the same location in every summary paragraph..
- There are no consistent delimiters or frequency..
- For example, you can't change the 5th instance of my_word..
- Only need to replace my_word in the summary paragraph

here's my approach so far

1) LOCATE **"Summary:"** in the textfield and get its index number.. LOCATE('Summary:',textfield) FROM mytable

2) SUBSTRING the summary paragraph.. SUBSTRING(textfield, index_from_locate)

3) REPLACE my_word in last summary paragraph.. REPLACE(substring,'**my_word**','new_text')

I can get good results from these three individual statements with Selects.. but I'm having trouble putting them all together into an update of the actual table/field that runs efficiently, e.g...

```
UPDATE myTable SET textfield = REPLACE((SELECT SUBSTRING(textfield, (SELECT LOCATE('Summary:',textfield)) ) FROM myTable WHERE created BETWEEN '2015-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-07-05 23:59:59'),'my_word','my_new_word')
```

how would I write an UPDATE to search and replace on only that specific summary paragraph using locate/substring/replace. . or similar syntax?

Many thanks

Comment: Why not just run a regex on the field value's ?

Comment: sql doesn't support regex fully? @sln

Comment: Hmmm .. interesting!   so just test to see if my_word is after "Summary:"  .. that could work ! . . there is only one instance and its always after "Summary;" ...   how do I do that with regex @sin ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is kind of old, but try this:

```
UPDATE test SET search_text = CONCAT( 
  CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING(search_text FROM 1 FOR (
      LOCATE('[my_word]',search_text,LOCATE('Summary:',search_text))-1)
      ),'[new_text]'
  ),SUBSTRING(search_text FROM 
    (LOCATE('[my_word]',search_text,LOCATE('Summary:',search_text))+CHAR_LENGTH('[my_word]')))
  )
WHERE created BETWEEN '2015-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-07-05 23:59:59'
AND search_text LIKE '%Summary:%[my_word]%'
```

(Wow, that is hard to format!)

Basically what it is doing is concatenating 3 strings: 1) the portion of the search_text before the [my_word] that you want to replace, 2) [new_text], and 3) the portion of the search_text after the [my_word] that you want to replace.

It is slightly more complicated than this because you doing want to replace the first occurrence of [my_word], instead the occurrence after 'Summary:'. So to do that correctly I find the location of 'Summary:', then the location of [my_word] after that location - and do that twice, once for the concat before [my_word] and once for the concat after.

**Notice:** This will only replace *one* occurrence of [my_word] after 'Summary:', if you need to replace multiple occurrences then you'll need to take a different approach. (Or write a script to run this query multiple times).

**Notice 2:** The second part of the WHERE clause `AND search_text LIKE '%Summary:%[my_word]%'` is very important. Without it then rows without [my_word] after 'Summary%' are updated in a strange way. Additionally, since this can be a very slow query the more clauses you can add to the WHERE statement the better.